# How to extract single element line by line and store in an array in Javascript?

Tags: javascript, arrays, node.js, google-maps

I've got a text file 'mytext.txt' with IPs and some text seperate by commas in different lines -

```
24.16.153.165:51413,abc
67.185.72.127:51413,xyz
69.247.183.46:63303,pqr
130.56.220.16:6881,def
```

I want to store the IPs in an array in JavaScript to plot them on a map. I found a way to do this by using a static array -

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('map'), googleMap);
var infowindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow();
google.maps.event.addListener(infowindow, "closeclick", function() {
                map.fitBounds(latlngbound);
                map.panToBounds(latlngbound)
            })
var ipArray = ["70.177.167.189", "123.135.107.115", "123.135.107.115", "123.135.107.115", "123.135.107.115", "122.182.6.19", "24.19.187.145", "24.19.187.145", "27.251.20.130", "27.251.20.130"];
ipArray.forEach((ip) => {
     addIPMarker(ip);
              })
    } catch(e){
        //handle error
}
```

Can someone tell me how to do it after extracting the IPs from the text file?  It should be a fairly simple logic, but I'm not very familiar with JavaScript. Thanks!

Comment: To clarify, do you mean you've gotten as far as getting the IPs as a single string in javascript?

Comment: No, I've succeded in mapping the IPs on the map from the array ipArray. I just need a way to extract the IPs from the text file and into the array.

Comment: Have you considered using node's built-in file system? https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html

Comment: As stated, I'm not very familiar with JavaScript and Node.JS. Could you tell me how to apply it in the given problem?

Comment: I provided a very generic answer. You will need to tweak it and please use the documentation to make sure you get what you need.

Answer (score 0):

This function works if you have a file on the server or another url.

```
function loadDoc() {
  var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
  xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function() {
    if (this.readyState == 4 && this.status == 200) {
        var myObj = this.responseText;
        var data = myObj.split(/\n/g);
        var data_ip = [];
        for(item in data)
        {

            var ip = data[item].split(/,/g);
            data_ip.push(ip[0]);
        }

        console.log(data_ip);
    }
};
xmlhttp.open("GET", "file.txt", true);
xmlhttp.send();
}
```

And this was work with a locally stored file.

```
function readTextFile(file)
{
    var rawFile = new XMLHttpRequest();
    rawFile.open("GET", file, false);
    rawFile.onreadystatechange = function ()
    {
        if(rawFile.readyState === 4)
        {
            if(rawFile.status === 200 || rawFile.status == 0)
            {
                var myObj = rawFile.responseText;                
                var data = myObj.split(/\n/g);
                var data_ip = [];
                for(item in data)
                {

                    var ip = data[item].split(/,/g);
                    data_ip.push(ip[0]);
                }

                console.log(data_ip);
            }
        }
    }
    rawFile.send(null);
}
readTextFile("file:///C:/your/path/to/file.txt");
```

Comment: I tried the 2nd (locally stored file) alternative, but, it didn't work as advertised! :(

Comment: Hmmm, you get a console error in it? and what about the first one?

Comment: I have the file locally stored in the same directory, so, I tried the 2nd alternative. Didn't get any console error!

Comment: ohh bro, if you have File in the same directory on the server then you have to use the first one, second used for the client machine not for the server machine.

Comment: I provide you the both suggestions for alertanave uses.

Comment: and one more thing If this article is related to your problem and solves your issue then use it as an answer to help another user to find the best option for there solution.

Answer (score 0):

To read a file in from your system you need to use the `fs` (file system) module provided by Node. You won't need to do any `npm install`.

JavaScript file:

```
const fs = require('fs');

const mapData = fs.readFileSync(//path to file here);

// do things with the data like your ip mapping, etc...
```

I have used the `fs.readFileSync()` function in the example but you will want to read the documentation and see what works best for your application.

Documentation:
https://nodejs.org/api/fs.html